# Upgrading libc from 2.19 to 2.28 causes X Window windows to not update properly when moved

Tags: linux, x11, glibc

I have an older `xorg` - `kdrive` X window environment that was working fine until updating the c library from 2.19 to 2.28 (needed because newer utilities and the 5.15 kernel needed a new gcc), however the updates to windows in X have artifacts (mainly on the right side) when you move a window around, but have seen where the text in a console window is messed up.  Moving the mouse cursor over part of it or minimize/restore then draws correct.  If you just use it normally without moving window around, it seems to draw okay.

I proved this by keeping everything the same and put back the 2.19 versions (everything 2.28 back to 2.19) and while some utilities didn't want to run due to missing items / needed 2.28, the x window system itself was working fine again.

Any ideas on why the `glibc` would affect that?   Is there any known issue with 2.28 and should I move to another one?

Comment: Which version of xorg ? Any good reason for not upgrading it ? Which package management system ?

Comment: The last version kdrive was available... looks like 1.12.2 ? it was built under etch a while back, I guess i could try the build on devuan beowulf (buster) to see if it matters.

Comment: 1.12 ? so I suspect it was built against the libc. in other words not the **g**libc